# How to group 3 hosts in ACE Ipv6 statement

Tags: ipv6, acl

I know for ipv6 ACE there is no wildcard mask, so if I want to add three hosts in one statement, for example, which prefix should I use for that network? (network `2001:db8:cafe:1/64`, `::1` reserved as default gateway, so I need to exclude `::2`, `::3` and `::4` only)

`/128` - 1 host  -- too few
`/127` - 2 host  -- too few
`/126` - 4 hosts -- too many

If I use `2001:db8:cafe:1::2/127`, it is missing `::4`,
while `2001:db8:cafe:1::2/126`, includes from `::0` - `::3`, so I am still missing `::4`,
plus adding `::0` which I do not want to.

Do I need to then use two ACE or it is possible to group those three hosts in one ACE?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to do it with one statement. You could use three `/128` statements, or one `/127` and one `/128`.

The zero address is the router anycast address, unlike the network address for IPv4, meaning it is probably only going to be a destination address, except for `/127` point-to-point links where you use it as the address of one end of the link.

Even with IPv4 wildcard masks, you wouldn't be able to get only those three addresses in one statement.